# json_decode returns null when I try to decode the response from youtube api

Tags: php, arrays, json, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

So I try to create a oauth connection with youtube api but I have a problem with decoding the response. My problem is here:

```
public function getCallbackUrl($code)
{

    // Grab the returned code and extract the access token.
    $this->params = [
        'code'          => $code,
        'client_id'     => '#####',
        'client_secret' => '####',
        'redirect_uri'  => '######',
        'grant_type'    => 'authorization_code'
    ];

    // Get access token
    $command = 'curl --data "' . http_build_query($this->params) . '" https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token';
    exec($command, $resultToken);
    $resultToken = json_decode($resultToken[0]);
```

After I make the exec `$resultToken` returns like this:

```
array(5) { [0]=> string(1) "{" [1]=> string(93) " "access_token" : "###########"," [2]=> string(26) " "token_type" : "Bearer"," [3]=> string(21) " "expires_in" : 3599" [4]=> string(1) "}" }
```

But when I try to json_decode to obtain an array: `$resultToken = json_decode($resultToken[0]);`
I get a result `NULL`
Can anyone explain to me why please? Any help is welcomed, thank you for your time!

```
var_dump($resultToken[0]) = NULL;
```

Comment: what is `var_dump($resultToken[0])` ?

Comment: Yes, show us the response body.

Comment: `$resultToken[0]` is not valid JSON. Check your response. Also consider using the [PHP cURL extension](https://php.net/curl) instead of directly using system calls.

Comment: Can anyone give me an idea on how to make my result into an array please?

Comment: I have not yet learned about curl and I need to get this over with quickly so I need to make use of what I have.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to decode a value which is not valid JSON. Verify whether your API request is returning the correct response. From [the documentation](https://php.net/json_decode):

> NULL is returned if the json cannot be decoded or if the encoded data is deeper than the recursion limit.

On a side note, you are using a system call to invoke cURL. Consider using the native [PHP cURL extension](https://php.net/curl) or a [proper library](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php).